# Find string in string and return a substring (Zapier)

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have a string like "localhost,GEWTESTID" or "GEWTESTID,localhost,somethingelse" etc.

Now I would like as an output = GEWTESTID

The string is always starts with "GEW" and 6 chars are following.

So what I need:

1. Find GEW
2. Find the next 6 chars (after GEW) (or go to next seperator = ",")
3. Output (1+2) = GEWTESTID

This I need working for Zapier Javascript code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you said you may have a string like "localhost,GEWTESTID" .. but then you say the string always starts with "GEW". Can you please make it more clear?

Comment: The string can be everything, but always GEWTESTID is included.

so: ABC,DEF,GEWTESTID,XYZ,QJD
or: DEF,GEWTESTID,ABC
...

Comment: it's such a confused question... you are actually saying you have a string that could be anything but it will always include the GEWTESTID part in it. Then you say your procedure is to look for GEW followed by 6 chars and finally the output is GEWTESTID where probably TESTID is not a literal TESTID but an actual code that could different any time. you have an answer and didn't give any feedback. I'm doubtful you'll get any further. Too much confusion and no clear focus on expectations.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I can't replay within few seconds on an answer when I try to use this code...

Answer (score 1):

We can try using string `match()` here with the pattern `\bGEW.{0,6}\b`:

```js
var inputs = ["localhost,GEWTESTID", "GEWTESTID,localhost,somethingelse"];
inputs.forEach(x => console.log(x + " => " + x.match(/\bGEW.{0,6}\b/)[0]));
```

To extract the Zapier substring, use:

```js
var input = "localhost,GEWTESTID";
var zapier = input.match(/\bGEW.{0,6}\b/)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you. This will give me the string I need as console log.
How can I get this result as a new var? THX!

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. One more thing. Can you check this image for me please?
https://i.ibb.co/SXpbTkS/Bildschirmfoto-2022-06-13-um-10-20-59.png

In Zapier I get this error: You must return a single object or array of objects.

Edit: I got it with "output = {zapier};"

Thank you very much!